# subsetting error in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a large `dataframe` called `dualbeta` which contains 2 rows and 6080 columns. Here is a sample:

```
row.names     A.Close   AA.Close    AADR.Close  AAIT.Close  AAL.Close
1   upside    1.253929  0.9869027   0.6169613   0.6353903   0.1782124
2   downside  1.027412  1.1936236   0.5915299   0.5697878   0.1702382
```

I am trying to extract only those with the `upside` >= 1.00 and those with a `downside` <=1.00. I used `combinations <- subset(dualbeta, upside>=1.00 & downside<=1.00)` but i get the following:

```
row.names   A.Close     AA.Close     AADR.Close  AAIT.Close 
1 NA          NA          NA            NA          NA  
2 NA.1        NA          NA            NA          NA  
3 NA.2        NA          NA            NA          NA  
4 NA.3        NA          NA            NA          NA  
5 NA.4        NA          NA            NA          NA  
...
```

It should just return a `2 by x` table where x is the number of combinations found. I do not know why I am getting a bunch of rows? Additionally, i thought i had `NA` values in the `dualbeta` so i used `na.omit(dualbeta)->dualbeta` but it deleted everything & turned `dualbeta` into a `0 by 6080`. I also used `which(is.na(dualbeta))` which returned `3307` and `3308` but when i checked those columns, they did not contain NAs.

Comment: `subset` operates on column names, not row values. So when you say `upside>1.00`, which value in that row is "upside"?

Comment: @MrFlick I see. but even if i use `combinations <- subset(dualbeta, dualbeta[1,]>=1.00 & dualbeta[2,]<=1.00)` i still get the same problem

Comment: Well, your first column is the name, right (`dualbeta[1,]`)?  How can the name "upside" be greater than 1.00? Didn't you get any sort of warning? Maybe you should replace your sample data with the results of `dput(head(dualbeta))` so we can see what type of object you are really working with.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I see, `dualbeta[1,]` is the row, not column. Anyway, you cannot use `subset` to subset columns like that. `subset` only works that way for rows.

Comment: @MrFlick `dualbeta[1,]` contains the values for `upside`. For example `dualbeta[1,1]` returns `1.253929` which is the upside for `A.Close`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might work on the transpose of the data in order to select rows  with the proper characteristics (which are columns in the transpose):

```
# Fix up the data, use proper row names
rownames(x) <- x$row.names
# Remove old row name column
x <- x[-1]

# transpose and subset
subset(data.frame(t(x)), upside > 1 & downside < 1)
```

This expression returns a zero-length result with your example data.  Changing the parameters shows what is returned:

```
subset(data.frame(t(x)), upside > .6 & downside < .6)
##               upside  downside
## AADR.Close 0.6169613 0.5915299
## AAIT.Close 0.6353903 0.5697878
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the data with simple indexing.

Let's say this is your data

```
dualbeta<-data.frame(matrix(runif(24,0,2), 
    nrow=2, 
    dimnames=list(c("upside","downside"), letters[1:12])))
```

then you can extract with

```
dualbeta[, dualbeta[1,]>=1.00 & dualbeta[2,]<=1.00]
```

Comment: This code returns: `Error in [.data.frame(dualbeta, , dualbeta[1, ] >= 1 & dualbeta[2, ] <=  : undefined columns selected`

Comment: @Jason I've added a sample dataset. From your description, it sounds like the same format as your data. I'm not sure how it could be different. The code works fine for me.